# Famous 403 Forbidden error when trying to access phpmyadmin. Windows 8

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

I am trying to use my wamp localhost but I am getting the famous error 403 when trying to access phpmyadmin, I have looked online for the possible solutions but nothing is working for me :(. I have already attempted to change phpmyadmin3.5.1 file but still not working. Can you please kindly help me with this issue. Many thanks

Comment: Is there any entry in the Apache web server log file?

Comment: Please tell us which solution you have tried. For example, did you look for "Deny" clauses in httpd.conf?

Comment: Please specifiy which version of WAMPServer and which Apache/PHP/Mysql you are using